# Area inside a curve and outside a Cardoid

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

For a National Board Exam:

> Find the area which is inside the curve r=3cos(theta) and outside the
>   cardoid r=1+cos(theta)

Answer is pi

Ok I am trying to setup the right definite integral for the calculator, I've tried:

Using the formula for finding area of polar curves:
$${ A = \int^b_a \frac{1}{2} f(\theta)^2 d\theta}$$

$${ A = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{1}{2} ( 3cos(\theta) - (1+cos(\theta)))^2 d\theta  = 3\pi}$$

What is the right integral?

Comment: 1) There are typos in your integrand. 2) You need to integrate over the range where $3\cos\theta \ge \max( 1 + \cos\theta, 0 )$, not over $[0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT...You need to establish where the curves intersect in order to determine the limits, so solve $3\cos \theta=1+\cos \theta$.

So your limits are $\pm\frac {\pi}{3}$

Comment: i use these as limits but i get 0.543... is it my calculator? i also try pi/3 to 5pi/3 and other iterations of the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

First figure out where the two curves intersect:

$$3\cos{\theta}=1+\cos{\theta}
\\ \cos{\theta}=\frac{1}{2}
\\ \theta=\frac{\pi}{3},\, \frac{5\pi}{3}$$

Then evaluate the areas inside the two curves and subtract, using these intersection angles as the bounds.